# Add positional index to a list

Tags: r, list

I would like to add a sequential element onto a list. Suppose I have the following list

```
lst <- list("A"=list(e1="a",e2="!"), "B"=list(e1="b", e2="@"))
$A
$A$e1
[1] "a"

$A$e2
[1] "!"

$B
$B$e1
[1] "b"

$B$e2
[1] "@"
```

I would like to append a `e3` which is the position index of that element in the list so essentially I would like my list to be:

```
$A
$A$e1
[1] "a"

$A$e2
[1] "!"

$A$e3
[1] 1

$B
$B$e1
[1] "b"

$B$e2
[1] "@"

$B$e3
[1] 2
```

Comment: Might I ask why? This seems like it could cause a lot of confusion and bugs if anything happens to change the order of items in the list. If you show us the problem this is solving, there might be a more robust solution.

Comment: This is for a calculation I am doing. I like to keep my values obvious

Comment: `for(i in seq_along(lst)) lst[[i]]$e3 <- i`

Comment: @akrun - my favorite answer as always, simple and straightforward :-). You should add that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `for` loop as well

```
for(i in seq_along(lst)) lst[[i]]$e3 <- i
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setNames(lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i){
    temp = lst[[i]]
    temp$e3 = i
    temp
}), names(lst))
#$`A`
#$`A`$`e1`
#[1] "a"

#$`A`$e2
#[1] "!"

#$`A`$e3
#[1] 1


#$B
#$B$`e1`
#[1] "b"

#$B$e2
#[1] "@"

#$B$e3
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Would this change the names?

Comment: @Denis, it shouldn't

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't assume that the sub-lists have the same known number of elements.

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("glue")

lst <- list("A"=list(e1="a",e2="!"), "B"=list(e1="b", e2="@"))

# The part
# `setNames(list(.y), glue("e{length(.x) + 1}"))`
# creates a one-element list named accordingly to append to the previous list
map2(lst, seq(lst),
     ~ append(.x, setNames(list(.y), glue("e{length(.x) + 1}") )))
#> $A
#> $A$e1
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> $A$e2
#> [1] "!"
#> 
#> $A$e3
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> 
#> $B
#> $B$e1
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $B$e2
#> [1] "@"
#> 
#> $B$e3
#> [1] 2

# If naming the additional element is not important, then this can simplified to
map2(lst, seq(lst), append)
# or
map2(lst, seq(lst), c)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) c(x, "e3" = y), x = lst, y = seq_along(lst))
#$A
#$A$e1
#[1] "a"

#$A$e2
#[1] "!"

#$A$e3
#[1] 1


#$B
#$B$e1
#[1] "b"

#$B$e2
#[1] "@"

#$B$e3
#[1] 2
```

This could be written even more concise as

```
Map(c, lst, e3 = seq_along(lst))
```

Thanks to @thelatemail

Comment: `Map` seems ideal for this. You could collapse this further too - `Map(c, lst, e3=seq_along(lst))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood correctly, that you want to add a 3rd element to each nested list which contains the index of that list in it's parent list. This works:

```
library(rlist)    
lst <- list("A"=list(e1="a",e2="!"), "B"=list(e1="b", e2="@"))
for(i in seq(1:length(lst))){
  lst[[i]] <- list.append(lst[[i]],e3=i)  
}
lst
```

Answer (score 1):

We can loop along the length of `lst` with `lapply`, adding this sequential index to each element.

```
lst2 <- lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) {
    df <- lst[[i]]
    df$e3 <- i
    return(df)
})
names(lst2) <- names(lst) # Preserve names from lst
```

Or, if you're not scared about modifying in place:

```
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) {
    lst[[i]]$e3 <<- i
})
```

Both give the same output:

```
$A
$A$e1
[1] "a"
$A$e2
[1] "!"
$A$e3
[1] 1


$B
$B$e1
[1] "b"
$B$e2
[1] "@"
$B$e3
[1] 2
```